# speechletResponse null error on alexa skill launch request

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I get an error when launching a skill.

```
SpeechletResponse was null
```

This is the response I see in my aws lambda cloudwatch

```
{
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "SSML",
      "ssml": "<speak>Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello</speak>"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": "<speak>Go ahead and say hello to me!</speak>"
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

This above response is a sample I am just returning, since it is mentioned on [this](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/handle-requests-sent-by-alexa.html) page(alexa documentation).

This is my code:

```
using Alexa.NET;
using Alexa.NET.Request;
using Alexa.NET.Response;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Function
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// A simple function that takes a input and returns an output
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SkillResponse FunctionHandler(SkillRequest input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine("Entered the function handler");
            context.Logger.LogLine("This is the request: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input));

            //RequestHandler

            //var output = new AlexaSkillsKit.Speechlet.SpeechletResponse()
            //{
            //    ShouldEndSession = true,
            //    OutputSpeech = new AlexaSkillsKit.UI.PlainTextOutputSpeech()
            //    { 
            //        Text = "This is alexa skills kit output."
            //    },
            //    Card = null,
            //    Directives = null,
            //    Reprompt = null
            //};

            ResponseBuilder builder = new ResponseBuilder();

            //var output = ResponseBuilder.Tell("Hello, sample output");
            var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkillResponse>("{" +
  "\"response\": {" +
                "\"outputSpeech\": {" +
                    "\"type\": \"SSML\"," +
      "\"ssml\": \"<speak>Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello</speak>\"" +
                "}," +
    "\"reprompt\": {" +
                    "\"outputSpeech\": {" +
                        "\"type\": \"SSML\"," +
        "\"ssml\": \"<speak>Go ahead and say hello to me!</speak>\"" +
                    "}" +
                "}," +
    "\"shouldEndSession\": false" +
  "}," +
  "\"version\": \"1.0\"," +
  "\"sessionAttributes\": { }" +
        "}");

            context.Logger.LogLine("This is the response: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output));

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Once Lambda sends response to the skill, this is the request that comes in from the alexa service, this is since it did not understand the response I sent earlier(shown above):

```
"request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.9e44df59-62fd-4a12-8568-6a701fadbe61",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "timestamp": "2020-05-12T21:47:56Z",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "SpeechletResponse was null"
        }
    }
```

I am banging my head to get past this error since 24 hours, but no luck. I tried different nuget packages etc. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was initially getting this error, because I did not deploy my python code from AWS lambda properly.

In general, if there is an error in response returned from lambda, alexa skill kit  developer reports this error.

To fix this, you can check the input json to the skill kit developer, check it if got the intent classified properly from the json input to the skill kit and use test feature in lambda to debug the error.